# Angular2 forms error when using JavaScriptServices/Universal

Tags: angular, angular2-universal

I have an Angular2 app that was created using the [JavaScriptServices starter](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices).

The problem that I am having is that I get a runtime error if I have a form in a component.

I am importing both **FormsModule** and **ReactiveFormsModule**.

My form looks like this...

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #loginForm="ngForm" >
...
</form>
```

The error I am getting is...

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Prerendering failed
>   because of error: TypeError: _angular_core.InjectionToken is not a
>   constructor at
>   C:\XXX\ClientApp\dist\main-server.js:35055:42

What have I missed? My form setup worked perfectly when I was not using the JavaScriptServices starter for server side rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I was using the most up to date version of Angular. It's not yet compatible.

After reading this GitHub issue page I found that reverting the Angular version fixed the issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13432

I am now using the below version and all seems well.

```
 "@angular/common": "2.0.2",
 "@angular/compiler": "2.0.2",
 "@angular/core": "2.0.2",
 "@angular/forms": "2.0.2",
 "@angular/http": "2.0.2",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.2",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.2",
 "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.2",
 "@angular/router": "3.0.2",
```